# Eliminar un registro de la base de datos en caso de no coincidir con un identificador que viene de un txt laravel

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos, postgresql, txt

Muy buenas tardes a todos, voy ponerlos en contexto rapidamente, estoy trabajando con un API en laravel que esta misma debe leer e insertar miles de datos masivos de personas de un txt, el codigo que realiza lo mencionado es el siguiente:

```
        public function store(Request $request)
        {
             $file = fopen($request->fileToUpload,"r");

            while(($column = fgets($file)) !== false){

                $column = explode(",", $column);
                $identification = $column[0];
                $codelec_id = $column[1];

                $name =  mb_strtoupper($column[5], "UTF-8");
                $last_name =  mb_strtoupper($column[6],"UTF-8");
                $second_last_name =  mb_strtoupper($column[7],"UTF-8");

                $characters = array(', ,','?', ',00000');
                $replaceFor   = array(',','ñ', '');
                $clearPersonName  = str_replace($characters, $replaceFor, $name);
                $clearLast_name  = str_replace("?", "Ñ", $last_name);
                $clearSecond_last_name  = str_replace("?", "Ñ", $second_last_name);

                //este es el metodo que yo llamo para realizar la verificación de los identificadores
                $this->checkIfTheIdentificationExist($identification);


               $data = [
                    ['codelec_id' => $codelec_id, 'name' => $clearPersonName, 'last_name'  => $clearLast_name, 'second_last_name' => $clearSecond_last_name, 'identify' =>  $identification, 'dead_or_alive' => false, 'phone' => null, 'email' => null, 'other_address' => null]
                ];

                $batchSize = 100;

                collect($data)->chunk($batchSize)->each(function ($batch) {
                   DB::table('people')->upsert($batch->toArray(),'identify');
                });

             }
             fclose($file);
   }
```

Mi problema está justamente acá y es el siguiente, necesito validar que los identificadores que se encuentran en la base de datos coincidan con los que voy leyendo en el txt, de no coincidir algún identificador, este identificador que pertenezca a un registro en la base de datos, se debe de eliminar, traté de realizar lo siguiente, pero no sé que está mal, NOTA: LOS IDENTIFICADORES SON DE TIPO UNIQUE

```
   public function checkIfTheIdentificationExist($identification)
   {
       //acá almaceno todos los identificadores que vengan del archivo txt
       //se almacenan en un arreglo unique
        $identifyArray = [$identification];
        $unique_array = array_unique($identifyArray);
       
        //hago una consulta a la base de datos para ver si ese identificador existe
        $people = DB::table('people')->whereIn('identify', $unique_array)->get();

        foreach ($people as $person) {
          //acá es donde trato de hacer la magia y validar que el identificador que no se encuentra o no coincida con los que están en el arreglo, sean eliminados
          if (!in_array($person->identify,  $unique_array)) {
              DB::table('people')->where('id',$person->id)->delete();
          }
       }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema con la función **checkIfTheIdentificationExist** es que siempre estás pasando un solo identificador a la función **$identification**, entonces **$identifyArray** y **$unique_array** solo tendrán un elemento.

Lo que puedes hacer es crear un arreglo fuera del ciclo **while** para almacenar todos los identificadores del archivo txt, y luego pasarlo a la función **checkIfTheIdentificationExist**. Así podrás comparar todos los identificadores del archivo txt con los de la base de datos.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo podrías modificar tu código:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $file = fopen($request->fileToUpload,"r");
    $identifyArray = []; // arreglo para almacenar todos los identificadores del archivo txt

    while(($column = fgets($file)) !== false){
        $column = explode(",", $column);
        $identification = $column[0];
        $codelec_id = $column[1];

        // resto del código...

        $identifyArray[] = $identification; // agregar el identificador al arreglo
    }

    fclose($file);

    $this->checkIfTheIdentificationExist($identifyArray); // pasar el arreglo de identificadores a la función
}

public function checkIfTheIdentificationExist($identifyArray)
{
    // hacer una consulta a la base de datos para obtener todos los identificadores que existen
    $people = DB::table('people')->whereIn('identify', $identifyArray)->get();

    // crear un arreglo con los identificadores que existen
    $existingIdentifiers = $people->pluck('identify')->toArray();

    // comparar los identificadores del archivo txt con los de la base de datos
    foreach ($identifyArray as $identification) {
        if (!in_array($identification, $existingIdentifiers)) {
            // eliminar el registro de la base de datos
            DB::table('people')->where('identify', $identification)->delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Con estos cambios, **$identifyArray** contiene todos los identificadores del archivo txt, y la función **checkIfTheIdentificationExist** recibe este arreglo y hace una consulta a la base de datos para obtener todos los identificadores que existen.

Luego, crea un arreglo con los identificadores que existen y los compara con los identificadores del archivo txt. Si un identificador no se encuentra en el arreglo **$existingIdentifiers**, entonces se elimina el registro correspondiente de la base de datos.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, justo lo que necesitaba